# Why does CSRF get validated when executing console command in Yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-validation

I'm trying to run a background process.
my idea is, execute a command in php which in turn run the console Yii2.

```
$result = exec('php yii controller/action param param > result.log &');
```

In Localhost everything works great, but the server does not work :(

shows me the message: "Unable to verify the data sent", this should not make sense since it is running from the console.

When I run the command directly from the console, everything is going well, but when the command is launched at runtime does not work.

Friends, thank you very much collaboration.

"This was translated from Spanish"

Comment: Do you extends your controller class from `yii\console\Controller`?

Comment: yes, it is.
My controller is:

<?php
namespace console\controllers;

use yii\console\Controller;

class controller extends Controller
{       
        
        public function actionAction(){
              // code ...
        }
        
}
?>